# mounting host OS drives to guest OS

Tags: virtualization, mount, ubuntu-9.04

I'm trying some server virtualization, and I need to mount a drive that is on the host OS (its E drive) to the guest OS (which is Ubuntu 9.04).

I am running in VMware Server 2).

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally find it is easiest to treat the computer as if it was simply another computer on the network.  Since it sounds like your Host OS is windows, I would share the drive/folder that you wanted access too, then your favorite cifs client in Ubuntu to access the folder.

- https://help.ubuntu.com/9.04/internet/C/connecttoserver-windowsshare.html
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountWindowsSharesPermanently

Answer (score 0):

Do you want access to the disk on BOTH operating systems? If so, you can use Shared Folders, but I'm fairly sure that this feature is not present in VMWare Server (only Workstation).

If you need to give exclusive access to the disk, then you can do this by editing the properties for the VM and adding a new disk. When it asks you which type of disk, choose Physical Disk (Advanced) and connect it that way.